# elements storing

Tags: c

code print elements after store them :

```
void print(struct node* root)
{

    while ( c != NULL ) 
    {
        printf( "\n%d ", c->line1);

        printf( "%s", c->curr );
        c = c->next;    
    }
}
```

print method

Comment: I'm going to assume it's a typo, but you have one too many `}` in this snippet, ending the `main` function just before the `print(root)` statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  When you post code to SO, it should be as nearly immaculate as possible.  It should compile.  It should be beautifully indented.  It should not be full of random blank lines (but neither should it be wall-to-wall code).  The `while` of your `do … while` is misplaced — or, more accurately, I suppose, the `print(root);` before it is misplaced.  The net result is that your loop is incomplete/incorrect — and won't compile.

Comment: I think, after correction in code, you must put `print(root)` out of the loop.

Comment: You are assigning a value to `conductor` — but `conductor` variable is not declared anywhere. It's not also used anymore after the assignment. Are you sure your code compiles...?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Are you sure your program 1) actually adds anything to the list and 2) exits the loop? That is, does the `getword()` function ever return `EOF`?

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the code, this line seems like a potential issue:

```
    temp->curr=current_input;
```

It looks like all the nodes .curr will get set = current_input. I'm guessing you need to do something like:

```
    temp->curr = malloc(1 + strlen(current_input));
    strcpy(tmp->curr, current_input);
```

Use strcpy_s if strcpy causes a warning.

Answer (score 0):

First you should realize a list consists of nodes, which contain pieces of your data — so you need to *allocate a new node for each piece of data* you want to store in a list.

Then you insert each newly created node into the list and finally print the list when done.

Additionaly remember that data need to be either copied into the node (like `line1`) or copied *somewhere else*, for example onto the heap, and then *linked* to the node with a pointer, like `curr` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32369862/733637) by @rcgldr).

```
struct node *root = NULL;

struct node *createnode(int line, const char *input)
{
    struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(n != NULL)
    {
        n->line1 = line;
        n->curr  = input;
        n->next  = NULL;
    }
    return n;
}

void insertnode(struct node* n)
{
    n->next = root;
    root = n;
}

void printlist(struct node* n)
{
    for( ; n != NULL; n = n->next)
    {
        printf( "%d: %s\n", n->line1, n->curr);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    char *input;
    struct node *temp;
    type t;

    do
    {
        t=getword(); //call to get the type of t

        switch (t) 
        {
        case number:
        case keyword:
            input = strdup(current_input);      // make a copy of user input
            if(input != NULL)
            {
                temp = createnode(line, input);
                if(temp != NULL)                // created?
                    insertnode(temp);           // insert into the list
                else
                {
                    free(input);                // free unused input copy
                    t = EOF;                    // make the loop terminate
                }
            }
            else                                // user input copy failed
                t = EOF;                        // make the loop terminate
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }   
    }
    while (t != EOF);

    print(root);

    return 0;   
}
```